# DateTimeFormatter format with a single pattern letter fails to parse short month name

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

I see the below error when I run the code listed below :

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text 'Thu Sep 21 23:47:03 EDT 2017' could not be parsed at index 4    at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.time.LocalDate.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.example.demo.DateTest.main(DateTest.java:16)

**Code**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "Thu Sep 21 23:47:03 EDT 2017";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E M d H:m:s z y", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
        System.out.println(date);           
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `M` as the month format specifier, but `M` is a number/text field, so it's expecting a numeric value.

I also suspect you mean `HH:mm:ss` rather than `H:m:s` for the time part, and `yyyy` for the year. (The latter is unlikely to be a problem unless you actually have dates before 1000AD.)

This works:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```